# Get label names from loaded model in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model

Is it possible to get the label names from an sklearn SGDClassifier model that is loaded from a pickle file?

```
model = pickle.load(open("saved_model.pkl", 'rb'))
y_pred = model.predict(x)
```

Because all the labels may not be present in the input vector, `x`, how can I know what the possible labels are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.classes_` will show the labels in the model. This is a public attribute of `SGDClassifier` object.

[Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html?highlight=sgdclassifier#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).